# Django channels как определить какой сервер нужен

Tags: django, redis, django-channels

Сейчас используется `nginx + uwsgi + supervisor + redis + postgresql`

Как примерно определить примерно (плюс, минус), какой нужен будет сервер, если `redis` и `postgresql` на той же `VPS`

Весь функционал для `channels`, только уведомления по принципу чата, где есть комната в зависимости от id пользователя

Я читал что `processes` примерно держат по 100 человек и если мне нужно 1000 в онлайн тогда их должно быть 10?

Пока `redis` только один, потому что функционала толком нету

Comment: Нагрузочным тестированием. Генерируете 1000 подключений и смотрите сколько ресурсов сервера это отъело.

Comment: мало знаком с этим, а примерно как это делать